# How to print each list in a lost separate by space?

Tags: python, list

For example list is
L = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
I want to print like

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in L:
    for j in i:
        print(j, end=" ")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop and indexing:

```
>>> L = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
>>> for i in L:
...     print(i[0], i[1])
...
1 2
2 3
3 4
```